# What is a control in web development?

Tags: html, web

I just read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739685/what-is-a-form-control-in-html) about the term "control" when dealing with forms.

However, the OP asked it in relation to Bootstrap, and I'd like know if this term has a general definition, and more importantly: Does its usage relates only to web forms, or does it have more usages in web development?

Comment: I'd be happy for a feedback on the reason for the downvotes. IMHO, it is a fairly legitimate question, not already found on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form controls are those elements (which you use in conjunction with a form) that the user interacts with directly. Examples include text boxes, drop down menus and buttons.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#sec-forms):

> A form is a component of a Web page that has form controls, such as text fields, buttons, checkboxes, range controls, or color pickers.

and

> Most controls are represented by the input element, which by default provides a one-line text field.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a "control" is a UI element which causes some action to occur. For example, both text inputs and submit buttons are examples of "control" UI elements.

There are special control elements implemented by specific frameworks or platform ecosystems. For example, there are many variations on calendar UI element controls.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the implementation issue. For future reference, I guess you can say [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461901/asp-net-control-to-html-tag-equivalent) post is related.